# Retrieve Youtube Tags using Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, youtube

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve Youtube Tags and use them in my code behind, but I can't even seem to retrieve any information whatsoever. What would be the best way to retrieve tags with a delimiter like a `,` or a `;` ?

```
  var video_id='VA770wpLX-Q';

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
alert(data.data.tags);
 });
```

This is what the Json object looks like:

```
 {
"apiVersion": "2.1",
"data": {
    "id": "VA770wpLX-Q",
    "uploaded": "2011-02-24T22:31:02.000Z",
    "updated": "2012-04-08T21:37:06.000Z",
    "uploader": "drdrevevo",
    "category": "Music",
    "title": "Dr. Dre - I Need A Doctor (Explicit) ft. Eminem, Skylar Grey",
    "description": "Music video by Dr. Dre performing I Need A Doctor featuring Eminem and Skylar Grey (Explicit). © 2011 Aftermath Records",
    "tags": ["Dr", "Dre", "Eminem", "New", "Song", "Skylar", "Grey", "GRAMMYs", "Dr.", "Need", "Doctor", "video", "Eazy", "N.W.A.", "NWA", "easy", "drdre", "and", "em"],
    "thumbnail": {
        "sqDefault": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VA770wpLX-Q/default.jpg",
        "hqDefault": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VA770wpLX-Q/hqdefault.jpg"
    },
    "player": {
        "default": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA770wpLX-Q&feature=youtube_gdata_player"
    },
    "content": {
        "5": "http://www.youtube.com/v/VA770wpLX-Q?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata"
    },
    "duration": 457,
    "aspectRatio": "widescreen",
    "rating": 4.902695,
    "likeCount": "430519",
    "ratingCount": 441253,
    "viewCount": 88270796,
    "favoriteCount": 306556,
    "commentCount": 270597,
    "status": {
        "value": "restricted",
        "reason": "requesterRegion"
    },
    "restrictions": [{
        "type": "country",
        "relationship": "deny",
        "countries": "DE"
    }],
    "accessControl": {
        "comment": "allowed",
        "commentVote": "allowed",
        "videoRespond": "allowed",
        "rate": "allowed",
        "embed": "allowed",
        "list": "allowed",
        "autoPlay": "denied",
        "syndicate": "allowed"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The above api does not give `tags`. I'm not sure where you got the json data from but the current api does not give tags anymore

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla that's unfortunate! How can I go about acquiring tags?

Comment: It does give out tags, but only to the video owner. You can go here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list, authorize your request with OAuth 2.0 and on your own videos you will be given tags. Sadly, this doesn't work with PHP API even with authentication due to some bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube no longer supports "tag" functionality with it's API.

Comment: You can get tags using API calls on your own videos after you authenticated with OAuth2 here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list